# Replacing values from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which have columns with strings and integers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ ['Manila', 5,12,0], ['NY',9,0,14], ['Berlin',8,10,6] ], columns = ['a','b','c','d'])
```

I want to change all the values to "1" where the value is greater than 1 and the zeros will be reamin the same.

So I tried with `apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 1 else 0)` but it shows its ambigious.

Then I tried to write a function separately as follow:

```
def find_value(x):

    try:
        x = int(x)
        print(x)
        if x > 1:
            x = 1
        else:
            x = 0
    except:
        return x
    return x
```

and then apply it

```
df = df.apply(find_value, axis=1)
```

But the output does not change and the df remains as it was.

I think there should be some apply function which can be applied on all of the eligible columns (those columns which has numerical values). But I am missing the point somehow. Can anyone please enlighten me how to solve it (with or without "map" function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for get numbers columns, compare for greater like `1` and then map `True, False` to `1,0` by casting to integers, for change data in original is used [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(np.number).gt(1).astype(int))
print (df)
        a  b  c  d
0  Manila  1  1  0
1      NY  1  0  1
2  Berlin  1  1  1
```

Or use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) if all integers and no negative numbers:

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(np.number).clip(upper=1))
print (df)
        a  b  c  d
0  Manila  1  1  0
1      NY  1  0  1
2  Berlin  1  1  1
```

EDIT:

Your solution working with [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = df.applymap(find_value)
```

Comment: Accepted as answer. worked perfectly. I Should put another question but still asking with due respect that is there any map which converts all the values to integers which are acutally integers but somehows saved as string in a dataframe?

Comment: @mdemt - Is possible identify this columns? E.g. `L = ['b','c']` - in columns `b,c` is possible numeric data are saved like strings?

Comment: @mdemt - Answer was edited for use your solution.

Comment: It is worth mentioning for the other newbies (like me) that, "update" operation by default is "inplace". So no need to re assign the value of df.

Comment: yes the solution worked perfectly. I used "df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore') " to convert the values first.